# Discord js check reaction user role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to close a ticket by reacting to a button. But reaction must be given by "support" role. I couldnt do it. reaction.message.member.roles.has is not helping me at this point. Here is my code ;

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
  if(reaction.message.member.roles.has('ROLE')) {
  let id = user.id.toString().substr(0, 4) + user.discriminator;
  let chan = `ticket-${id}`;

  const supchan = reaction.message.guild.channels.find(
    (channel) => channel.name === chan
  );
  const chan_id = supchan ? supchan.id : null;

  if (
    reaction.emoji.name === "" &&
    !user.bot &&
    user.id != "ID"
  ) {
    reaction.removeAll();

    const channel = client.channels.find("name", chan);
    const delMsg = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor("#E74C3C")
      .setDescription(`:boom: Ticket will be deleted in 5 seconds.`);

    channel.send(delMsg).then(() => {
      var counter = 0;

      const intervalObj = setInterval(() => {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 5) {
          const message = reaction.message;
          message.delete();
```

Thanks for helps !

Comment: Hi there! It is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you please elaborate? What error are you getting (if any)?

Comment: Sorry about that. When specified role is clicking the emoji nothing happens. Only owner of ticket can close with this code

Answer (score -1):

All of this wrapped inside the `messageReactionAdd` event

```js
// Replace "message_id" with the proper message id
// Checks if it's the correct message
if (reaction.message.id == "message_id") {

     // Check if author of ticket message is from the same user who reacted
     if (reaction.message.author == user) {

          // Check correct emoji
          if (reaction.emoji.name == "") {
               // Code to close ticket
          }

     }

}
```

**EDIT:**
Again, this would be wrapped inside the `messageReactionAdd` event:

```js
// Try to get the ticket message
// If there's none then the user was never opened a ticket so we simply return the code
const ticketMessage = client.tickets.get(user);
if (!ticketMessage) return;

// Checks if it's the correct message
if (reaction.message.id == ticketMessage.id) {

     // Check correct emoji
     if (reaction.emoji.name == "") {
         // Code to close ticket
     }

}
```

I removed the code that check for the reaction message author because getting `ticketMessage` already handles that. Do note that this means you can make sure a user can only open one ticket.

Comment: But the message_id is not always the same. Person creates a ticket and bot creates a channel if person creates a ticket.

Comment: Yea. So basically in your command to create a ticket, you save that user inside a Map with the user as key and the value as the message. For example: `client.tickets = new Map()`. In your command: `client.tickets.set(message.author, ticket_msg)`. Let's assume you have done that, view the edited answer above.