# How to check if the original message sender reacts discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My current code is

```
            message.channel.send(dungeonEmbed).then(sentEmbed => {
                sentEmbed.react("⚔️")
            })
```

this sends the embed, and reacts, but I need to figure out a way to check if the original message sender reacts, and to then replace an embed with another

Comment: You'll need to set up a reaction collector. [Learn Basic Reaction Collectors Here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want.
Let's guess you want if the author reacts on his own message

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.message.id == "The message ID" && user.id == reaction.message.author.id){
        //The author and the original message has reacted
        if(reaction.emoji.name == ""){
            //The author has reacted the specified emoji
        }
    }else{
        //Just in case
    }
})
```

Please also check this one too [Discord js check reaction user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61375794/discord-js-check-reaction-user-role)